# AlertDialog compose title with Image

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose-material3

In AlertDialog on compose, do you know if its possible in the title field, to put an Image plus a title ?

I am trying to do something like

```
title = {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Image(
            imageVector = image,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
        Text("Title")
    }
},

text = {
    Text("test text")
},
```

The problem is : I think the title in AlertDialog has a specific size, so my Image is crop.

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

With **M3** `AlertDialog` (`androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog`) it works.

[image]

With **M2** `AlertDialog` you can remove the `title` attribute and use the `text` attribute for the whole layout.

```
AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = {},
    text = {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
            Text("Title")
            //.....
        }
    },
    buttons = {}
)
```

Comment: Hi @Gabriele Mariotti, M3 alert dialog working fine, but always it is showing the bottom of the screen. How do we display the AlertDialog center of the screen?

Comment: hi @Gabriele Mariotti sorry to bother you but if the image is the first element, it will be crop. It weird, but if I put the image between 2 text, it will work. Do you know how can i fix that?